# Just how out of date are the major 19th/early 20th century English grammars of Latin (G&L, A&G, Bennett)

Tags: grammarians, pedagogy

In the late 19th and early 20th centuries, there were a slew of Latin grammars published in English that stuck around are still popular today (in the Anglophone world). A survey of various resources online point to these three as the chief major ones:

- Gildersleeve and Lodge (1894)
- Allen and Greenough (1903)
- Bennett (1918)

These have all had various updates throughout the year, but if someone were to get an out-of-copyright reprint, what sort of serious problems might they encounter? An easy example is the prosody section of Allen and Greenough, which Anne Mahoney thoroughly reworked recently. Are there other problematic areas, and have they since been corrected?

Feel free to recommend other grammars that might fit the bill, even if it's not in English.

Comment: To be clear, you are talking about grammars written in English? Because the ones you mention I have never used (first heard about them on this website), as opposed to Kühner–Stegmann, Van der Heyde (probably only in Dutch).

Comment: @Cerberus I would personally welcome a post on grammars in Dutch, too, if you're so inclined, but I am indeed primarily looking for grammars in English. I actually deleted English from the title and then forgot to put it in the body of the text!

Comment: There is [12.a](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/accents) : "When an enclitic is joined to a word, the accent falls on the syllable before the enclitic, whether long or short." -> for what I understand this statement at least conversational and probably wrong.

Comment: @Cerberus As you probably know, the two volumes of the recent _Oxford Latin Syntax_ by Pinkster were intended to update and then replace the monumental work by Kühner & Stegmann. My experience is that there has been no such replacement (unfortunately for me since my German is quite limited...). I've realized that in many aspects K&S still provides richer and more useful syntactic information & data than Pinkster!

Comment: @Mitomino: Ah, thank you for the information. I had heard of Pinkster's Syntax but not seen it yet. I shall continue to use the excellent and publicly available K–S.

Comment: @Mitomino: I am not familiar with K & S. If your German "is quite limited" how do you know that it's better than Pinkster's? The assumption is that you are not enamoured of Pinkater's vol. II, recently-published, is that correct?

Comment: @Mitomino Is Pinkster's *Oxford Latin Syntax* the best Latin grammar book in English?

Comment: @Tim Harm Pinkster's 2 volumes of his OLS are indeed very useful and very detailed (with lots of attested examples). However, if you're interested in "grammar" (not just in syntax), you should know that you won't find a treatment of morphology there. In this sense, I'd not refer it to as "the best Latin _grammar_ book" but, if you're basically interested in syntax, Pinkster's 2 volumes published by the Oxford University Press (vol. 1 in 2015 & vol. 2 in 2021) are indeed a very good choice.