# What is the "fairly outdated grammatical apparatus" in Allen and Greenough's New Latin Grammar?

Tags: grammarians, linguistics

[Please recommend Reference Grammar for someone with an undergraduate degree in Linguistics](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/11201/please-recommend-reference-grammar-for-someone-with-an-undergraduate-degree-in-l) says:

> I don't know if this commenter had known of the [2006 edn of *Allen
> and Greenough's New Latin
> Grammar*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486448061)
> when (s)he wrote:
>
> > Allen and Grenough is the standard traditional grammar, but like most Classics grammars, it was written well before the advent of
> > modern linguistic theory, and thus is burdened with a fairly outdated
> > grammatical apparatus. Most of the accidence is fine, excepting some
> > of the historical material, but the book's syntactic description is
> > less reliable, IMO.

What is the "fairly outdated grammatical apparatus" in
Allen and Greenough's New Latin Grammar? What is not linguistic about it?

Comment: Related: https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/16273/just-how-out-of-date-are-the-major-19th-early-20th-century-english-grammars-of-l